# PHP, date is offset by 1 day. Going from DOY (Y-z) format to string/unix

Tags: php, datetime, date-format

I'm required to take a date in the format 'Y-z' which is year-doy (e.g, 2013-146) and convert that into a unix time stamp to be store into a database.

The issue i have is that i input 2013-146 and turn it into a DateTime Object.  then when i output this date in unix or 'Y-m-d' format i get 2013-5-27 not 2013-5-26 which is the correct day.

You can verify the DOY on this [NASA website](http://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/julian_calendar.shtml) and this [NOAA website](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/neubrew/Calendar.jsp?year=2013&col=4).

Summary:
--I have the date: '2013-146' 
--Using DateTime::createFromFormat and echoing using 'Y-m-d' and 'Y-z' i get:  2013-5-27 and 2013-146 respectively.
--This does not agree with the NASA website I listed and is offset by one day can anyone verify that I'm not losing my mind?

Here is the code you can test:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$year = 2013;  //where this outputs a simple year 'CCYY'
$day = 146;        //where this provides the day of year

$format = 'Y-z';    //specifying what format i'm creating the datetime with
$date = $year.'-'.$day;         //formatting the strings to the above $format
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago');     //specify the timezone
$fileDateStore = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date, $timezone);//, $timezone);  //create the DateTime object
$fileDateString = date_format($fileDateStore,"Y-m-d");  //format it so strtotime() can read it
$fileDate = strtotime($fileDateString);  //finally create the Unix Timestamp for the date.
$newfileDOY = date_format($fileDateStore,"Y-z");
echo 'newfileDOY = '.$newfileDOY.', ';
echo 'date = '.$date.', ';
echo 'fileDateString = '.$fileDateString.', ';
echo 'fileDate = '.$fileDate.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: It's probably a timezone issue. `2013-146 3am` Chicago is `2013-145 9pm` or whatever in UTC.

Comment: I thought that too but I'm not storing a time. Also I'm careful to force the default time zone to be Chicago for use in `date_format()` and `strtotime()`. I also when creating the time zone `DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')` and place that into `DateTime::createFromFormat` so twice i'm forcing the time zone to 'America/Chicago'

Comment: yes, but internally EVERY php timestamp/datetimeobject has an implicity time. if you don't specify one, it'll be `00:00:00`, and if you move between timezones (even if it's purely within PHP), those "midnight" times will get adjusted to/from local/utc times as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is than `z` format in PHP begins with 0 and not with 1.

Look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> **z**:     The day of the year (**starting from 0**)

Comment: In addition (support) to this answer, From the manual: `z: The day of the year (starting from 0)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver if you are building the date string in php, add 1 to use elsewhere. If you were taking a date string from elsewhere, then you would -1 day in php.

Comment: oh my god... s.m.h., face palm, what ever.   thank you very much for doing the book keeping.